# printf %f with dynamic length

Tags: java, format, printf

In my printf, I want to print a double type variant with dynamic length. Like %fn.2, but the n is a int variant and its value is determined in runtime. How can I write this code in java?

Comment: A more detailed [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could concatenate a string like

```
static PrintStream formatDouble(PrintStream stream, double value, int precision) {
    return stream.printf("%." + precision + "f", value);
}
```

This is the most straightforward way to do it, but there are other ways too